# How to securely read data from a packet in C?

Tags: c, security, operating-system

How can I read data from a packet in C and convert it into a structure? I mean, there's a structure like

```
|=======================================================================
|0123456701234567012345670123456701234567012345670123456701234567.......
|  type  |             length            |    MSG HDR    |    data
```

into a struct like

```
struct msg {
  char type;
  size_t length;
  int hdr;
  struct data * data;
};
```

Is the following code fine?

```
bool parse_packet(char * packet, size_t packet_len, struct msg * result) {
    if(packet_len < 5) return false;
    result->type = *packet++;
    result->length = ntohl(*(int*)packet);
    packet+=4;
    if(result->length + 4 + 5 > packet_len)
      return false;
    if(result->length < 2)
      return false;
    result->hdr = ntohs(*(short*)packet);
    packet+=2;
    return parse_data(result, packet);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your application doing?

Comment: What are your security concerns?

Comment: I want to not have buffer overflows/read overruns (eg. heartbleed)

Comment: @user3623227: That's not "secure". That's just "correct", which is implied anyway.

Comment: Your casts produce undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: What is the correct, fully-specified way to convert from a byte array to integer with host endianness?  `memcpy` into a `uint32_t` then call `ntohl` on that?

Answer (score 1):

It's usually good practice to check that `packet` and `result` are non-null.

Why are you checking that `packet_len < 5` when the header is 7 bytes?  Why not just ensure that the packet is at least 7 bytes and get it over with?  Or is `hdr` not present for some `type`?

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with

```
if(result->length + 4 + 5 > packet_len)
    result->hdr = ntohs(*(short*)packet);
packet+=2;
```

If the declared message length plus nine is greater than the received message length, you read another two bytes from the message.  Then regardless of the length of the data, you add two to the pointer and try to parse something out of it.  What if `packet_len` is 5 and `result->length` is 4294967295?  You're going to read off the end of your buffer, just like in Heartbleed.  You need to always verify that your reads are in bounds, and never trust the size declared in the packet.

Comment: the check was broken - fixed it.

Comment: How are you guaranteeing that you've read the entire message before you call `parse_packet`?

Answer (score 1):

You have a completely standard situation. There's nothing deep or surprising here.

Start with a *specification* of the wire format. You can use pseudo-code or actual C types for that, but the implication is that the data is packed into bytes on the wire:

```
struct Message  // wire format, pseudo code
{
    uint8_t    type;
    uint32_t   length;      // big-endian on the wire
    uint8_t    header[2];
    uint8_t    data[length];
};
```

Now start parsing:

```
// parses a Message from (buf, size)
// precondition: "buf" points to "size" bytes of data; "msg" points to Message
// returns true on success
// msg->data is malloc()ed and contains the data on success
bool parse_message(unsigned char * buf, std::size_t size, Message * msg)
{
    if (size < 7) { return false; }

    // parse length
    uint32_t n;
    memcpy(&n, buf + 1, 4);
    n = ntohl(n);            // convert big-endian (wire) to native

    if (n > SIZE_MAX - 7)
    {
        // this is an implementation limit!
        return false;
    }

    if (size != 7 + n) { return false; }

    // copy data
    unsigned char * p = malloc(n);
    if (!p) { return false; }
    memcpy(p, buf + 7, n);

    // populate result
    msg->type = buf[0];
    msg->length = n;
    msg->header[0] = buf[5];
    msg->header[1] = buf[6];
    msg->data = p;

    return true;
}
```

An alternative way of parsing the length is like this, directly:

```
uint32_t n = (buf[1] << 24) + (buf[2] << 16) + (buf[1] << 8) + (buf[0]);
```

This code assumes that `buf` contains *exactly* one message. If you're taking messages off of a stream, you need to modify the code (namely the `if (size != 7 + n)`) to check if there is *at least* as much data available as required, and return the amount of consumed data, too, so the caller can advance their stream position accordingly. (The caller *could* in this case compute the amount of data that was parsed as `msg->length + 7`, but relying on that is not scalable.)

**Note:** As @user points out, if your `size_t` is not wider than `uint32_t`, then this implementation will wrongly reject very large messages. Specifically, messages for which it is not true that `7 + n > n` will be rejected. I included a dynamic check for this (unlikely) condition.

Comment: `7 + n` could overflow (which I think is undefined).  It's safer to check that `size - 7 != n`, since we've already checked that `size` is at least 7.  But +1 for the detailed answer.

Comment: @user3553031: Interesting, but unsigned arithmetic is well defined and standardized, so the equality check `size != 7 + n` works, and inequality (`size >= 7 + n`) would also be fine -- if there were an overflow, the check would simply fail. This is an implementation limitation: If your `size_t` has the same width as `uint32_t`, then you cannot use this parser for large messages, and you need to set up a partial parser.